# WebApi Routing: api/{controller}/{id} and api/{controller}/{action} at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have default webapi routing configuration:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
);
```

I want to support following scenarios:

```
//api/mycontroller
public IQueryable<MyDTO> Get();

//api/mycontroller/{id} where id can be anything except "customaction1" and "customaction2"
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id);

//api/mycontroller/customaction
[HttpPost]
public void CustomAction1([FromBody] string data);
[HttpPost]
public void CustomAction2([FromBody] string data);
```

I have tried to apply `[Route("api/mycontroller/customaction1")]` to the `CustomAction1` method, and similar to `CustomAction2` but getting:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
>   CustomAction1 on type MyProject.WebApiService.MyController
>   CustomAction2 on type MyProject.WebApiService.MyController

Comment: Did you configure attribute routing? `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`

Comment: Nope. Tried and works. I will accept is as asnwer. However it is possible to configure the routing so it will work by default with the custom action without the attributes?

Comment: You would have to create more routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you configured attribute routing along with your default configuration

```
//....
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
);
//....
```

If you want to do the same with out attribute routing then you will need to configure routes explicitly

```
//This one constrains id to be an int
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action="Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints : new { id = @"\d" }
);
//This one should catch the routes with actions included
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionRoutes",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

Comment: well, in my case id is any string except the action names

Comment: Oh i missed that. thought it was an `int`. this does change things.I will have to  recheck